# Schedule DAG to run once in a two months on last Sunday

Tags: python, cron, airflow

I need to run my Airflow DAG **once in a two months on last Sunday at 3 am**. For Example February's last Sunday, April's last Sunday, June's last Sunday and etc. (It skips January, March, May and etc)
I was thinking of using this cron expression, but it does not work as I want.

```
0 3 * */2 7


dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval='0 3 * */2 7',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 1),
    max_active_runs=1
)
```

How can I achieve this result in one cron expression? Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend choosing a date, i.e. 27th.

But if you have such specific requirement, there are somewhat advanced ways to guess if it is the **last** Sunday.

Disclaimer: There is no direct flag or syntax to achieve the desired date/time, you have to do some calculations in order to guess if this Friday is the last of the month.

1. Not so good way:
   Digging around I found that you have to calculate if it is last
   Sunday, even in bash as follows:

```bash
00 3 * * 0 username [ $(date +"\%m") -ne $(date -d 7days +"\%m") ] && your-script.sh
# it is checking whether the month on this friday is equal to month on coming Friday. 
# If not then means today is the last friday.
```

---

2. Pythonic way: [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/scheduler.html#dag-runs) documentation states that either [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) syntax as string or a `datetime.timedelta` object.

You can use that to gain computation power of python for this purpose.

---

3. Sadly here we cannot inherit this syntax:

Wikipedia states in [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) definition:

> **Non-standard characters**
>
> *The following are non-standard characters and exist only in some cron implementations, such as the [Quartz Java scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(scheduler)-).*
>
> **`L`:**
>
> 'L' stands for "last". When used in the day-of-week field, it allows specifying constructs such as "the last Friday" ("5L") of a given month. In the day-of-month field, it specifies the last day of the month.
>
> Which means your requirement can be written as `0 00 03 ? */2 1L` but it is in *[Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(scheduler)-)*